# gradients in tailwind have a break when using h-screen

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have the following issue on content that exceeds the height of the screen viewport.

[image]

As you can see, there is a hard break with the gradient, where it should be smooth.

```
      <body className="font-inter min-h-screen h-screen dark:bg-dark-background dark:text-dark-text-primary bg-gradient-to-br from-gray-800 to-gray-900">
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
```

How should I set my CSS so this does not happen?

Comment: Did you scroll on your screenshot ? You're at the top of the page ?

Comment: @OneQ I scrolled, but it only consumes the viewport. Irrespective of screen height, the break is always at viewport height.

Comment: You mean that the gradient is 100vh ? That's what h-screen does no ?

Comment: I want the gradient to take the entire screen, the contents extend beyond the viewport because it scrolls (ie blog article), but it continues to repeat. I want a smooth gradient the entire screen, not just viewport.

Comment: If you remove h-screen and let min-h-screen, isn't it good ?

Comment: no, the same problem persists.

Comment: Do you have something else in your code ? Do you have more info ? 
Because I tried here : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-tailwind-starter-forked-1e4nwb?file=/src/index.css

Comment: Down to move into chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250799/discussion-between-ryan-and-oneq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in global.css

Had to remove

```
html {
  @apply h-full;
}
body {
  @apply h-full;
}
```